# Wiremock to serve Images stored on local disk

Tags: wiremock

Can wiremock be used to create a mock endpoint that will serve images stored on local disk (`Content-Type: image/jpeg`) ? I am on Wiremock 1.58.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in wiremock [user group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wiremock-user/XY9zw1M3AGo), creating a folder as shown below:-

[image]

and then added it as the root folder of wiremock by the below code:-

```
WireMockConfiguration config = new WireMockConfiguration();
config = config.withRootDirectory("src/test/resources/server_path/").port(56789);
WireMockServer mockServer = new WireMockServer(config);
```

The image was then accessible by hitting `http://localhost:56789/nike.jpg`